# Using regex to extract strings given a pattern in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to figure out how to grab only the values in between known begin and end strings.  For example, using this string:

```
I need [?Count?] [?Widgets?]
```

I need the the values **Count** and **Widgets** returned.

I tried

> [?(.*)?]

and ended up with

```
I need [
Count
] [
Widgets
]
```

Is there a way, using these begin and end strings, to parse out the values I need?  Or should I try and find a way to change them before parsing out the values? I really appreciate any help you can provide.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var str = "I need [?Count?] [?Widgets?]";
$(str.match(/\[\?.*?\?\]/g)).map(function(i) { return this.match(/\[\?(.*)\?\]/)[1] });
// => ['Count'], 'Widgets']
```

Note that in the regex, you have to escape `[`, `]`, and `?` as they are special characters. Also use the `g` flag at the end of the regex to find all matches. I'm also using `.*?` instead of `.*` -- that means non-greedy match or "find the shortest possible match", which is what you want here.

Finally, the results are mapped (using jquery `map`) to remove the '[?' and '?]' from the results.

Or, if you don't want the special characters removed, don't even use the map:

```
var str = "I need [?Count?] [?Widgets?]";
str.match(/\[\?.*?\?\]/g);
// => ['[?Count?]'], '[?Widgets?]']
```

Comment: Thank you Ben.  Using those characters probably wasn't the best.  Your function works great.  I really appreciate your help :)

Answer (score 1):

In your regular expression try `\[\?([^\?]*)\?\]`

Comment: Note that instead of `[^\?]*` you can just do `.*?`: The latter means "match the shortest possible match", which in this case will be everything up until the first "?]" it finds, but nothing more.

Comment: Thanks verybadbug. In using Ben's str above, I tried this: var p = str.match(\[\?([^\?]*)\?\]); but can't get it to work because of the syntax.  Am I missing something obvious?  thank you.

Comment: missing backslash for first and last brackets